# Unity GameObjects still show in the hierarchy after they have been destroyed

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine

I have some programmatically created Text objects that I would like to delete after I've updated an XML list of them. For some reason, they aren't deleted. They still show in the hierarchy.

The XML is simply a file with a root element and player elements with name attributes.

Here's the code:

```
public GameObject textTemplate;
public InputField nameInput;

// list of player names
private List<GameObject> players = new List<GameObject>();

private const string playersPath = "foo/bar.xml";

// this is a button OnClick callback
public void TryAddNew()
{
    // get name from input field
    string name = nameInput.text;

    if (players.FirstOrDefault(t => t.GetComponent<Text>().text == name) == null)
    {
        // update XML

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(playersPath);

        XElement root = doc.Element("players");
        root.Add(new XElement("player",
            new XAttribute("name", name)
        ));

        doc.Save(playersPath);

        LoadPlayers();
    }
}

private void LoadPlayers()
{
    // destroy existing player texts
    foreach (GameObject obj in players)
    {
        // THE PROBLEM IS HERE, this doesn't seem to work
        UnityEngine.Object.Destroy(obj.GetComponent<Text>());
        UnityEngine.Object.Destroy(obj);
    }
    players.Clear();

    // load players from XML

    XDocument users = XDocument.Load(playersPath);

    XElement root = users.Element("players");

    int i = 0;

    foreach (XElement playerEle in root.Elements("player"))
    {
        CreateNewPlayerText(playerEle.Attribute("name").Value, i);
        i++;
    }
}

// instantiate new player text
private void CreateNewPlayerText(string name, int index)
{
    GameObject newObj = Instantiate(textTemplate) as GameObject;

    // insert into parent view
    newObj.transform.SetParent(textTemplate.transform.parent);

    Text newText = newObj.GetComponent<Text>();
    newText.text = name;
    newText.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(SCROLL_MARGIN, -SCROLL_MARGIN - index * 15);

    // show text
    newObj.SetActive(true);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to destroy both the component and the game objet, destroying the game object destroyes all components attached to it too.

Comment: Yes, that was just one thing I tried when trying to get this to work

Answer (score 0):

I never added the text GameObjects to the list. I had to add this to the end of the CreateNewPlayerText method:

```
players.Add(newObj);
```